# Why are my processes in MySQL disappearing for some reason?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, unix

When I do:

```
show processlist
```

I see all my 20 servers connected to it. But, after a while, they drop off one by one. I know it's not the script problem. **My script does Not terminate.**

Could it be that it time-out if it doesn't make a query within a certain time? How do I change that setting?

Edit:
The python script selects and inserts into the database every 1-3 minutes.

Comment: What does your setup look like? Do you have 20 database servers? Connected to what?

Comment: What kind of 'scripts' are connecting to your database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a daemon (background) process running which maintains a connection pool, your connections will close after your script terminates.